# Go output with ioutil: returning array of (ASCII?) numbers from http call

Tags: http, go

I am trying to write a web client in Go, but when I check the return value of the body of the http request, I get an array of numbers, instead of text.

This is the most isolated version of the program that produces the output. I think I am failing do something with ioutil, but do not know what.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "io/ioutil"

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://test.com/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Print(body)
}
```

The output comes out looking like:

[239 187 191 60 33 68 79 67 84 89 80 69 32 104 116 109 108 ...

instead of the test returned by test.com

Comment: Thanks icza! Newbie mistake, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ioutil.ReadAll()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) returns a byte slice (`[]byte`) and not a `string` (plus an `error`).

Convert it to `string` and you're good to go:

```
fmt.Print(string(body))
```

See this simple example (try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cr-dwDLDAS)):

```
var b []byte = []byte("Hello")

fmt.Println(b)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Output:

```
[72 101 108 108 111]
Hello
```

Comment: If you want to avoid creating a separate string, you can also just write the value to stdout (`os.Stdout.Write(b)`).

Comment: If you want to use [fmt](http://godoc.org/fmt) and avoid the string, then use `fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)`.